# Error when restoring model (Multiple OpKernel registrations match NodeDef)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm getting an error when attempting to restore a model from a checkpoint.

This is with the nightly Windows GPU build for python 3.5 on 2017-06-13.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): 
Multiple OpKernel registrations match NodeDef 'Decoder/decoder/GatherTree = GatherTree[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:CPU:0"](Decoder/decoder/TensorArrayStack_1/TensorArrayGatherV3, Decoder/decoder/TensorArrayStack
_2/TensorArrayGatherV3, Decoder/decoder/while/Exit_18)': 'op: "GatherTree" device_type: "GPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_INT32 } } }' and 'op: "GatherTree" device_type: "GPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list { type: DT_
INT32 } } }'[[Node: Decoder/decoder/GatherTree = GatherTree[T=DT_INT32, _device="/device:CPU:0"](Decoder/decoder/TensorArrayStack_1/TensorArrayGatherV3, Decoder/decoder/TensorArrayStack_2/TensorArrayGatherV3, Decoder/decoder/while/Exit_18)]]
```

The model is using dynamic_decode with beam search, which otherwise works fine in training mode when not using beam search for decoding.

Any ideas on what this means or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same issue a day ago. Turns out it was a [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11277) in tensorflow. It's resolved now and BeamSearchDecoder should work with the latest build of tensorflow.